# Android - one date and two time pickers in one dialog

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I want to have one date and two time pickers in one dialog and I have done it, but the second time (Time to) is getting the same values as (time from).  I have put some 'if cases' to try to fix it but didn't help. I get ("2016/10/27 5:41 0:00) even if I pick the time for the two "timepickers" I don't get the value for the second one or it duplicates the first one.

**here is my code:**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


import java.util.Calendar;





public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    //firebase auth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //view objects
    private TextView textViewUserEmailadmin;
    private Button buttonLogout;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private EditText editTextinfo;
    private TextView Textpass;

    private Button buttonSave;

    int day, month, year, hour, minute,hour1,minute1;
    int dayFinal, monthFinal, yearFinal, hourFinal, minuteFinal,hourFinal1,minuteFinal1;

    int i = 0;
    Button btnDatePicker;
    String a="";
    String b="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        //initializing firebase authentication object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        editTextinfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //initializing views
        textViewUserEmailadmin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmailAdmin);
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);


        //displaying logged in user name
        textViewUserEmailadmin.setText("Welcome admin " + user.getEmail());

        //adding listener to button
        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);


        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
       // btnTimeFrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time_from);
       // btnTimeTo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time_to);


        Textpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textviewpass);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private void saveUserInformation() {
        String info = editTextinfo.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = Textpass.getText().toString().trim();


        i++;
        UserInformation UserInformation = new UserInformation(info, pass);
        // FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //databaseReference.child(user.getUid()+i++).setValue(UserInformation);
        databaseReference.child("tidnr" + i).setValue(UserInformation);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Information saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //if logout is pressed
        if (view == buttonLogout) {
            //logging out the user
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            //closing activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
        if (view == buttonSave) {
            saveUserInformation();
        }

        if (view == btnDatePicker) {

            if(a == "" && b == "") {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AdminActivity.this, AdminActivity.this, year, month, day);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        yearFinal=i;
        monthFinal=i1 +1;
        dayFinal= i2;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if(a == "" && b == "") {
            android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            //is24HourFormat = dateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AdminActivity.this, AdminActivity.this,
                    hour, minute, dateFormat.is24HourFormat(this));
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int i, int i1) {
        hourFinal = i;
        minuteFinal = i1;
        String curTime = String.format("%02d",minuteFinal);


       if(a == "" && b == ""){

            a = yearFinal+"/"+monthFinal+"/"+dayFinal+"  "+hourFinal+":"+curTime;
       }




        if(a != "" && b == "" ) {

            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour1 = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute1 = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat1 = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            //is24HourFormat = dateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog1 = new TimePickerDialog(AdminActivity.this, AdminActivity.this,
                    hour1, minute1, dateFormat1.is24HourFormat(this));
            timePickerDialog1.show();
            String curTime1 = String.format("%02d",minuteFinal1);
            b = a+"  "+hourFinal1+":"+curTime1;
            a="";

            Textpass.setText(b);
            Toast.makeText(this, "test.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
String curTime1 = String.format("%02d",minuteFinal1);
b = a+"  "+hourFinal1+":"+curTime1;
```

with:

```
String curTime1 = String.format("%02d",minute1);
b = a+"  "+hour1+":"+curTime1;
```

Comment: it didnt help, now im getting a number in the second one but not the time im choosing.